# How to disable the Azure Bastion for Virtual Machine in Azure cloud?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-vm-scale-set, azure-vm

I am using a Virtual Machine in Azure portal. Over there, I connected the VM via RDP. Now when I saw at my credits $19 are spent and the uses by Azure Bastion.

After it, I did some R&D and figured out how to delete all Azure Bastion resources via Azure PowerShell. I deleted all Azure Bastion and checked with this command `az network bastion network` and the list is empty.

After a day, I again connected the VM via RDP and today when I checked the used details, it has increased by $4.

My question is, why is this happening even after deleted all bastion resources in Azure Portal and how can I stop it completely because I don't want to be charged more?

Comment: You realise that the VM itself costs money, right?

Comment: Ya, I know VM itself costs money but it is very low. And the azure bastion has spent $19 in only 4 days. And I run the VM only for 3-4 hours a day.

Comment: Can you check Azure Cost Management to see where the cost is?  It could be a number of things adding up, e.g. VM compute costs, VM licensing, disk storage costs, disk transactions, backup, public IP address, monitoring costs etc.  It all adds up.  Also, the Cost Management usage is not in real time so there may have been a delay in seeing some of the costs incurred for Azure Bastion.  It can take a day or more to catch up sometimes.

Comment: @AlanKinane Thanks for your words, you hit multiple answers for others also. You should compose it as the answer. It will really help others.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please use the below command to check all the azure bastion hosts.

```
az network bastion list
```

If any bastion hosts are present, you can delete them using below command :

```
az network bastion delete --name MyBastionHost --resource-group MyResourceGroup
```

After deleting your bastion host, make sure to delete your public IP created for bastion host.

Please use the below command to delete public IP :

```
az network public-ip delete -g MyResourceGroup -n MyIp
```

Please refer the below document for the pricing of Bastion :

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/azure-bastion/

Comment: I got the following response for the first two commands you've mentioned.       This command is in preview and under development. Reference and support levels: https://aka.ms/CLI_refstatus